# Why does my function only see the initial state of react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a game and I need to start a timer when it starts and stop when the state value is > 9 to stop it, but the problem is that it doesn't happen.

Here is the timer:

```
const [update, setUpdate] = React.useState(0);
const startTimer = () => {
  let value = 0;
    const timerI = setInterval(function(){
      value = value + 1/60;
      console.log(update);
    if(update > 9){
      setResultGame(value.toFixed(2));
      if(value < record){
          setRecord(value);
      }
      clearInterval(timerI);
    }
    }, 1000/60);
}
```

It is worth clarifying that he sees only the initial value of the state "update = 0"
I change this state in another function via useState:

```
const verifingSpell = (spell) => {
  if(spell === randomSpell){
    generateSpell();
    setUpdate(update + 1);
    console.log(spell,arr);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting a *new* interval on every render?  For something like `setInterval` you *probably* want to make use of `useEffect` and return a function from the effect to clear the interval.  Though an interval might not even be the right tool for the job here.  You can also achieve a "timer" in React with simply updating the state after a timeout, which triggers a re-render and a new timeout.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you're observing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setUpdate`, the state will be queued to change on the next render. But the `function` inside `startTimer` can only see the first value of `update` inside its [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

As a workaround, you can store the latest value of `update` in a ref. But you should first consider if there is a way to refactor your component's logic so that this is not required.

```js
const [update, setUpdate] = React.useState(0);
const updateRef = React.useRef(update);
React.useEffect(() => updateRef.current = update, [update]);
```

Then, you can check `updateRef.current`:

```js
if (updateRef.current > 9) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: The _closure_ is the key, @Ilia: `update` inside the inner function will always retain its original value

Comment: You can see my github ? https://github.com/iturturika/Invoker-game/blob/develop/src/App.js

Comment: I tried what you said and unfortunately nothing has changed.

Comment: @Ilia It doesn't look like you added a ref.

Comment: I tried your suggestion again today and it helped me thanks.